# Javascript IFFE TypeError "string" is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Have a look into the es6 code below:

```
let person = "John Malkovich"
(() => {
  console.log("Original person was ", person);

  person = "Drew Barrymore";

  console.log("New person " + person);
})();
```

When I execute this program it throws me this error:

```
"TypeError: \"John Malkovich\" is not a function
```

Now I know that if I add a `;` at the end of line 1 i.e `let person = "John Malkovich";` the program works. My only headache is not being able to understand why that weird error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the syntax is valid up to this point, an opening parentheses following an expression (perhaps with a newline in between) will result in the interpreter trying to invoke the expression as a function. That is:

```
someExpression()
```

or

```
someExpression ()
```

or

```
someExpression
()
```

will all try to invoke `someExpression`. No semicolon is automatically inserted because if `someExpression` happens to be invokable, the syntax is valid. (ASI generally only inserts semicolons, to separate distinct statements from each other, when the syntax would be invalid otherwise)